# How can a feature that when removed, does not affect the model's performance not be declared unimportant?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, boruta

In the paper on the [Boruta](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i11) algorithm, there is a statement that is unclear to me (highlighted in black).

> The all-relevant problem of feature selection is more difficult than usual minimal-optimal one.
> One reason is that we cannot rely on the classification accuracy as the criterion for selecting
> the feature as important (or rejecting it as unimportant). **The degradation of the classification
> accuracy, upon removal of the feature from the feature set, is sufficient to declare the feature
> important, but lack of this effect is not sufficient to declare it unimportant.**

My questions are:

1. How can a feature that when removed, does not affect the model's performance not be declared unimportant?
2. Is there a scenario that can exemplify this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One immediate example which comes to my mind would be a case where predictors are highly co-linear. If you have two covariates which are highly correlated, removing one of them will improve the performance of your model. Yet, it does not mean that the removed covariate was not relevant to predict your outcome variable. Here is an example with R from [there](https://book.stat420.org/collinearity.html) :

```
library(faraway)
hip_model = lm(hipcenter ~ Age + Arm + Ht + HtShoes, data = seatpos)
# Adjusted R2 = 0.62
hip_model_small = lm(hipcenter ~ Age + Arm + Ht, data = seatpos)
# Adjusted R2 = 0.63
hip_model_deletedfeat = lm(hipcenter ~ HtShoes,data=seatpos)
summary(hip_model_deletedfeat)
```

Running this code, you will see that removing the HtShoes variable in your model will effectively increase the accuracy of your model but it does *not* mean that HtShoes is irrelevant since, if you regress your outcome variable on this covariate alone, you see that the relationship is statistically significant.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer and reproducible code. I do not quite understand this: If you have two covariates which are highly correlated, removing one of them will improve the performance of your model. Is it going to improve because of ob the colinearity?, should no the performance remain the same since both features "carry the same information" to the model?

Comment: When you do model building, you are facing a trade-off between bias and variance. In this case if you have variables which are multicolinear, you have inflated the variance of your estimators (for intuition, think of perfect co-linearity of two random variable : X1 and $X2 := \alpha X_1 + \beta$ , when you have two predictors which are perfect L.C of each other then one can predicted knowing the other and so you are expressing one-dimensional information in two dimensions.

Comment: The fact that both X1 and X2 give information on the same dimension make their estimates higly variable therefore inflating the standard errors of the estimated parameters of a model with highly colinear predictors.

Comment: Does that apply to tree-ensemble models? Or is it only on linear ones?

Comment: Bias variance trade off or multicolinearity issues ?

Comment: the multicollinearity issue

Comment: check out the following https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31402/multicollinearity-in-decision-tree